# Flutter Cloud Firestore compile error: CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, compiler-errors

[image: Here is the error]

I am getting an error message when I run my app with the cloud_firestore: 0.13.7 plugin. But it still builds the app. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't provide screenshots of text.  Copy the text into the question itself, and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a warning, in your `build.gradle` file change the minSdkVersion to version `21` and run the app again.

Answer (score 1):

I changed minSdkVersion to 23 from 21(or prior maybe), and it works cool.