# Problem with adding firebase to my android app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I attempting to add Firebase to my Android app and I faced this problem with configuring root project 'android'
[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNxAp.png)
And this code for project/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this code for app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.water_reminder_app"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.fatima_hure.water_reminder_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried to change the version number `classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services: 4.2.0'` also, I tried adding Firebase plugins to an Android project using the buildscript syntax but this not work too. anyone can know how to fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have searched about it and it seems that firebase has updated their firebase integration now their are two ways to integrate with firebase one is with **1. buildscript(so by default you will have buildscript) in buildscript method also they have changed the code for integration** and other one is with **2. plugin(new one)** you can check it out by going to your firebase project settings and than scroll down you will see on "See SDK instruction" button click on it and there you will find new way to integrate it.
**Troubleshoot & FAQ link**
https://shorturl.at/auAIP

Other than this you can also use flutterfire CLI it's much better and easy way to integrate firebase to you flutter app here is the guidance link if you want to check it out
https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-firebase-flutterfire-cli/

Comment: this not work too

Comment: which error is it showing now ?

Comment: You can see the error in this link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J01EFkN5fxGC1rJnFTtljba2mho7595v/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have updated the answer you can check it out now.

Comment: I followed the third option to add Firebase to my app and I got this error `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be... minSdk version to at least 19,` because of cloud_firebase and firebase_auth when I deleted them from the pubspec.yaml it worked for me. But I don't know how to use firebase cloud and auth without getting this error again.

Comment: Go to your android>app>build.gradle and change minSdkVersion to 21 and then again add cloud_firebase and firebase_auth package and restart your app.

Comment: And yes don't forget to add SHA1 key to your firebase project settings. To generate key go to your android folder using terminal and type ./gradlew signingReport for linux or  gradlew signingReport for vs code or android studio there you will find SHA1 key copy it and paste that key in your firebase project settings.

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't work until I replaced this line `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion` and I wrote instead `minSdkVersion 21` then it worked for me. Thank you so much, Shaurya Kajiwala

Comment: but when I run the app it shows me this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62734371/flutter-cloud-firestore-compile-error-cloudfirestoreplugin-java-uses-unchecked) it is okay to have this?

Comment: It will cause no problem but for safety you should resolve it. You can check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781271/11958777